# Android project creation errors

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I just installed Android for eclipse and created an android project. When i build and try to run the project for the first time, eclipse shows errors in three XML files that were generated when creating the project:

```
res/values/styles.xml
res/values-v11/styles.xml
res/values-v14/styles.xml
```

I get these error messages below in the console. I have no idea why this would happen in an automatically generated project setup. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
[2014-03-20 13:30:25 - Ny] W/ResourceType(11996): ResXMLTree_node data size 0x80000 extends beyond resource end 0x156.   
[2014-03-20 13:30:25 - Ny] C:\Users\DigohD\Documents\GitHub\Ny\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.ny'
[2014-03-20 13:31:42 - Ny] W/ResourceType( 6564): ResXMLTree_node size 0 is smaller than header size 0x100.    
[2014-03-20 13:31:42 - Ny] C:\Users\DigohD\Documents\GitHub\Ny\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.ny'    
[2014-03-20 13:41:40 - Ny] W/ResourceType(15616): ResXMLTree_node data size 0x80000 extends beyond resource end 0x156.    
[2014-03-20 13:41:40 - Ny] C:\Users\DigohD\Documents\GitHub\Ny\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.ny'    
[2014-03-20 13:42:08 - Ny] W/ResourceType(16232): ResXMLTree_node header size 0 is too small.    
[2014-03-20 13:42:08 - Ny] C:\Users\DigohD\Documents\GitHub\Ny\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.ny'    
[2014-03-20 13:45:00 - Ny] W/ResourceType(15680): ResXMLTree_node data size 0x80000 extends beyond resource end 0x156.    
[2014-03-20 13:45:00 - Ny] C:\Users\DigohD\Documents\GitHub\Ny\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.ny'
```

Comment: Yes I think so. At least I have the virtual device manager installed and working.

Comment: I changed the Android version to 4.0 and now it works fine. Weird though, since i had the previous one installed.